# Add active class to the closest of <li> if <li> tag have any active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code.

```
<div class="support-menu hidden-xs">
<nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="active">Basic SQL</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="Database_Basic" target="_self" href="~/Database/Basic">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a class="Database_SQLSyntax" target="_self" href="~/Database/SQLSyntax">SQL Syntax</a></li>
                    <li><a class="Database_Select" target="_self" href="~/Database/Select">SELECT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="">SQL Function</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="Database_AVG" target="_self" href="~/Database/AVG">AVG</a></li>
                    <li><a class="Database_COUNT" target="_self" href="~/Database/COUNT">COUNT</a></li>
                    <li><a class="Database_MIN" target="_self" href="~/Database/MIN">MIN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the script to add active on li tag based on URL.

```
<script>
 var index = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + '_' + 
window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
$('ul.li.a').removeClass('active');
$('a.' + index).addClass('active');
 </script>
```

So what I want is when the li tag have active class then also add active class on parent a (anchor) tag

Comment: have you tried `console.log` to see what the value of `index` is when you're trying to do this?

Comment: `$('ul.li.a')` should either be `$('ul li a')` or `$('ul, li, a')`

Comment: Well js code is working fine it does not have any problem the thing which I want is to detect if li have active class then add active to its parent a tag.

Comment: you are right but existing code is working according to my expectation.

Comment: Even though this is doable, I might recommend not redundantly applying style names.  For example, you can just apply the `active` class to the parent and then style its child `a` tag with `.active a { ... }`

Comment: I have to support @snapjs on the logic. And on a sidenote, I see the "parent anchor" you want to select is actually not a parent.

Comment: Ohh, thank you, I understood now anchor tag is not a parent of li class thank you just now I noticed. So is there any way to add active on a then good else I have to make little changes in my code to make it the parent of li class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have not tested your code, as you said that this is working fine than add below code in your script tag.

```
$('a.' + index).closest('div').siblings().removeClass('active');
$('a.' + index).closest('div').prev('a').addClass('active');
```

assign these selectors to variables if you want to skip repeating those.

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery line should do it:

```
$('a.' + index).closest('div').prev().addClass('active');
```

With closest() it searches for all the parents with tagname DIV and selects the one closest to you A element.
And with .prev() you select the element above the DIV, which is in this case the A element.